# Keep the file extension when force the download

Tags: angularjs, html, download

I'm developing a website for a company that allows people to send your CV. During sending the file I change his name to a string based on the time of form submission to avoid that already exists a file with the same name on the server.

Then, through a control panel, you can download this CV submitted.
Once this sequence makes no sense to the user, when it downloads the file I change its name to the name of the person who sent it.

So I have a "button" that looks like this:

```
<a href="./uploads/{{ row.attachment }}" download="Curriculum Vitae - {{ row.name }}" target="_blank" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">
    <i class="fa fa-download"></i>
</a>
```

The problem is that the uploaded file can be in various formats. Can be PDF, DOC, DOCX, TXT, RTF...
How can I do to change the file name, but keep your extension?

Comment: You can split the file name by '.' and change only the first substring

Comment: I'm doing it with SQL. But I wondered if the HTML5 provides a more elegant way to change only the filename, keeping the extension.